# Does one fullfill mitzvah of Tziszis still for the day if he just dons Tallis Gadol for Shacharis?

Tags: tzitzis, tallit-gadol, tallit-katan

If a person is hesitant to wear tziszis all day (because, for example they own dogs that will ruin it), and that person only dons the Tallis gadol for Shacharis and then at Mincha time dons a tallis katan and then again removes it after davening Mincha. Is that fine?

Does that person still fullfil the mitzvah of tziszis for the day that way?

My second question is: If one day a person can't don tziszis in the afternoon with tallis katan do they still fulfill the mitzvah of tziszis for the day since they donned the tallis gadol at shacharis for shema and amidah?

Comment: Wearing Tzitzis a whole day is not an obligation, but is still very recommendable. also, although some hold that one should have the Tzitzis untucked, one would still fulfill the Mitzvah even if they are tucked in

Comment: To further clarify @שלום's point. There is no "daily" obligation of *tzitzit*. The only obligation is in the case where one wears a four-cornered garment, one must have *tzitzit* on the corners. That said, general practice it to fulfill this *mitzvah* as often as we can, by wearing four-cornered garments whenever possible. (As alluded to in your question, there are also separate reasons to specifically be wearing a *tallit* / *tzitzit* during various prayers.)

Comment: Is there really an issue in wearing a talit katan tucked inside? A dog wouldn't see it nor would others in most scenarios

Answer (score 2):

The question appears to contain a mistaken premise. There is no daily obligation to wear sisith. However any time one wears a four cornered garment, they are obligated to wear sisith upon it. This is similar to other elective miswoth, such as mezuzah... there is no obligation to live in a house which would require a mezuzah, one can live in a tent or on a boat their entire life mezuzah free and have done nothing wrong. There is however a slight difference when it comes to sisith. The Rambam writes (H. Sisith 3:10-12):

> היאך חיוב מצות הציצית:  כל אדם שהוא חייב לעשות מצוה זו--אם יתכסה בכסות
> הראויה לציצית--יטיל לה ציצית, ואחר כך יתכסה בה; ואם נתכסה בה בלא
> ציצית, הרי ביטל מצות עשה.  אבל הבגדים הראויין לציצית--כל זמן שלא יתכסה
> בהן אדם, אלא מקופלין ומונחין--פטורין מן הציצית:  שאינה חובת הטלית, אלא
> חובת האיש שיש לו טלית. אף על פי שאין אדם מחוייב לקנות טלית ולהתעטף בה,
> כדי שיעשה בה ציצית, אין ראוי לאדם חסיד, לפטור עצמו ממצוה זו; אלא לעולם
> ישתדל להיות עטוף בכסות המחוייבת בציצית, כדי שיקיים מצוה זו.  ובשעת
> התפילה, צריך להיזהר ביותר; גנאי גדול הוא לתלמיד חכמים, שיתפלל והוא
> אינו עטוף. לעולם יהא אדם זהיר במצות ציצית, שהרי הכתוב שקלה ותלה בה כל
> המצוות כולן, שנאמר "וראיתם אותו וזכרתם את כל מצוות ה', ועשיתם אותם"
> (במדבר טו,לט).
>
> What is the nature of the obligation of the commandment of sisith?
> Every person who is obligated to fulfill this mitzvah, if he wears a
> garment requiring sisith, should attach sisith to it and then wear it.
> If he wears it without attaching sisith to it, he has negated [this]
> positive commandment. There is, however, no obligation to attach
> sisith to a garment which requires sisith, as long as it remains
> folded in its place, without a person wearing it. It is not that a
> garment requires [sisith]. Rather, the requirement is incumbent on the
> person [wearing] the garment. **Even though a person is not obligated to
> purchase a talleth and wrap himself in it so that he must attach
> sisith to it, it is not proper for a pious person to release himself from
> this commandment. Instead, he should always try to be wrapped in a
> garment which requires sisith so that he will fulfill this mitzvah. In
> particular, care should be taken regarding this matter during prayer.**
> It is very shameful for a Torah scholar to pray without being wrapped
> [in a talleth].A person should always be careful regarding the mitzvah
> of sisith, because the Torah considered it equal to all the miswoth
> and considered them all as dependent on it, as [implied by Numbers
> 15:39]: "And you shall see them and remember all the miswoth of God."

Even though the obligation of sisith is only triggered by electing to wear a four cornered garment, it is nevertheless proper to endeavor to wear it - especially at times of prayer. Every time that you put on a four cornered garment that properly has sisith, you are actively fulfilling the miswah. And every time you don it for the purpose of prayer, you are fulfilling the exhortation of the hakhamim that you strive to do so at such time. If you are able to do so additionally throughout the day, that is wonderful. If you are not able to do so due to other practical considerations that impede your ability to do so, there is nothing defective in such practice.

Comment: So if i'm not able to or dont don tallis katan for whatever reason at Mincha but i donned tallis gadol at Shacharis for Shema and amidah, that also counts as doing mitzvah of tziszis for the day? I always don tallis katan for mincha im just asking if i dont or not able to at a time. Not looking for leniencies or shortcuts G-d forbid. B"H.

Comment: Any time that one dons a properly qualified garment with sisith during the daytime, a miswah is fulfilled. There is no obligation to wear sisith daily. Despite the lack of an obligation, our Sages teach that it is meritorious to attempt to wear sisith as often as practically possible - especially during prayer. If one does not wear sisith on a given day, or for the duration of a particular prayer, there is no defect.

Comment: @Niel I also wish to politely remind you that Mi Yodeya "[does not offer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/can-i-consult-mi-yodeya-as-i-would-a-rabbi) personalized, professional advice, and does not take the place of seeking such advice [from your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi). Questions and comments in this forum ought be framed as generic inquiries rather than personalized solicitations of halakhic ruling. I see that you are a new user and may not be as familiar. Welcome!